# Return a number of elements depending on the array dimension

Tags: arrays, typescript, element

I have a variable dimension arrangement.

How is it possible to show or return a number of Data's elements equal to the dimension of the array without having so many conditionals. Since, in the first instance, the dimension of the arrangement is not known. This could have a dimension of 1 or 100, etc.

```
const Elements = (props:{arrangement:any}) = > {

  if (arrangement.length==1){
   return(
     <Data name={arrangement[0][0]} last_name={arrangement[0][1]} ></Data >
   )
  }
  if (arrangement.length==2){
   return(
     <Data name={arrangement[0][0]} last_name={arrangement[0][1]} ></Data >
     <Data name={arrangement[1][0]} last_name={arrangement[1][1]} ></Data >
   )
  } 
  // ......
  if (arrangement.length==10){
   return(
     <Data name={arrangement[0][0]} last_name={arrangement[0][1]} ></Data >
     <Data name={arrangement[1][0]} last_name={arrangement[1][1]} ></Data >
      ..........
     <Data name={arrangement[9][0]} last_name={arrangement[9][1]} ></Data >
   )
  } 

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Add

```
const ExploreContainer  = (props:{arreglo:any}) => {

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log(props.arreglo)
   
  }, []);

  return (

    <div >
      <Elements arragement={props.arreglo} />
    </div>
   
  );
};

const Elements = (props:{ arrangement: Array<any> }) => {

  return (
  
  props.arrangement.map((a) => {

     <CardExamples item={a[0]} nombre={a[1]} distancia={a[2]} dias={a[3]} hora_ini={a[4]} hora_fin={a[5]} calificacion={a[6]}></CardExamples>  

    })
    )
}

const CardExamples= (props:{item: React.ReactNode, nombre: React.ReactNode, distancia: React.ReactNode, dias: React.ReactNode,
  hora_ini: React.ReactNode, hora_fin: React.ReactNode, calificacion: React.ReactNode  }) => {
   return (
    <IonCard>
          <IonCardHeader>
            <IonCardTitle>{props.nombre}</IonCardTitle>
            <IonCardSubtitle>{props.item}</IonCardSubtitle>
            <IonItem> CALIFICACIÓN: {props.calificacion} </IonItem>
          </IonCardHeader>
          <IonItem>
            <IonLabel>Imagen de servicio</IonLabel>
          </IonItem>
      <IonCardContent>"Descripcion"</IonCardContent>
      <IonItem><IonButton fill="outline" slot="end">View</IonButton></IonItem>

    </IonCard>
       
  );
};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

New

this shows me the first element

```
const Elements = (props:{ arrangement: Array<any> }) => {
    return(
      <div className="container-principal">
             <CardExamples item={props.arrangement[0]} nombre={props.arrangement[1]} distancia={props.arrangement[2]} dias={props.arrangement[3]} hora_ini={props.arrangement[4]} hora_fin={props.arrangement[5]} calificacion={props.arrangement[6]}></CardExamples>  

  </div>

    )
}
```

But this does not show anything:

```
const Elements = (props:{ arrangement: Array<any> }) => {

return (
    <div className="container-principal">
    {
  props.arrangement.map((a) => {
     <CardExamples item={a[0]} nombre={a[1]} distancia={a[2]} dias={a[3]} hora_ini={a[4]} hora_fin={a[5]} calificacion={a[6]}></CardExamples>  
     console.log(a[0])

    })
  }
  </div>
    )
}
```

Why can it be?

Comment: remember to return in the map function

Comment: it will show empty if you do not return ```CardExamples```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from looking at your sample code provided I would suggest that you use modern TS/JS mapping function to properly map your data into the result you have above.

Here are modifications you can make to your code:

```
// First, looks like you have a syntax bug here that, should look like this
const Elements = (props:{ arrangement: Array<any> }) => {
    /*
     * The map function call is callable on array types, it lets you remap your array,
     * with a callback that lets you return any other type using the element in the
     * array that you have to manipulate.
     */
    
    // so we map arrangement so that each element of arrangement is passed to the call
    // back function we provided as a, then we can return whatever we want. in this case
    // the HTML.
    return props.arrangement.map((a) => {
        return `<Data name="{a[0]}" last_name="{a[1]}"></Data>`
    });
}
```

So basically the function you provide in the `map` arguments is used when iterating the array such that `a` is and element of `arrangement` due to the iteration.

UPDATE:

Spelling is important :'D - `<Elements arrangement={props.arreglo}/>`

Okay since you are using this function as a component in a react app you must consider that the function returns an array of elements not just one element, so
you need to wrap the return of the function in a `div` or something. like so:

```
//...
return (
    <div>
        {
            props.arrangement.map((a) => {
                return (<Data name="{a[0]}" last_name="{a[1]}"></Data>)
            });
        }
    </div>
)
//...
```

I used this as a reference [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/understanding-how-to-render-arrays-in-react)

I hope I have answered your question.

Comment: Thanks. But what I get is: 'Elements' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'void[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'void[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

Comment: Can you add more context to your problem by sampling the code in which you are using the function ```Elements```. I would like to see what data is provided to the function

Comment: @ Ashwyn Horton - I Added how the code is implemented in the first message

Comment: Thanks. I did other modification